# jquery validation plugin not working fine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1 for form validation , my problem is its not working properly

in this html code

```
<input name="Mobile" type="text" class="Input" id="Mobile" placeholder="Type your mobile number" value="<?php echo $activeUser->getMobile();?>" required="true" number="true" />
```

`required="true"` working fine,but `number="true"` not working

please help me to solve this
thanks

Comment: which plugin are you using? Can you give an url to projectpage of the plugin?

Comment: Please provide info of the plugin

Comment: Are you using http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ plugin?

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is factored for HTML 5 validation...

```
<input name="Mobile" type="text" class="Input" id="Mobile"
placeholder="Type your mobile number" value="" required="true" number="true" />
```

This would be no problem for a more updated version (like 1.11.0) of the jQuery Validate plugin.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5rPGv/2/**

However, your same code is broken when using version 1.8.0 of the jQuery Validate plugin.

**Broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/5rPGv/1/**

---

To fix your code, you only have two options:

1)  Update the jQuery Validate plugin to a later version.

OR

2)  Declare your rules within `.validate()`, with any version.  http://jsfiddle.net/5rPGv/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            Mobile: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `additional-methods.js` into your page. You should have `mobileUK` validation method or. Try using :

```
<input name="Mobile" type="text" class="Input" id="Mobile" placeholder="Type your mobile number" value="<?php echo $activeUser->getMobile();?>" required="true" mobileUK="true" />
```

**EDIT**

If html version doesn't work try setting that with JS :

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      mobileUK: true
    }
  }
});
```

You can create your own validation type. Example : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```